# Why not embed images as base64 strings in WYGIWYS editors

Tags: html, http, base64, wysiwyg, data-url

Wanted to do add some WYSIWYG editor right now to my site. Due to inconvenience for managing file uploads (need to do some work for several hours), I wanted to find some editor, that able to edit text and embed images in it as `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,STUFFSTUFFSTUFFHERE"` - data URL.

I didn't find such editor, so now I'm thinking, that there's might be a certain purpose, that makes unavailable to spread such kind of image processing way.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Because data url is not widely supported (read: old IE)?

Comment: Did you find such an editor? I am looking for one

Comment: Unfortunatly, I had to implement my own. That was fun, but it wasn't complete enough to share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you embed the images that way the size of the page increases too much:

- The encoded images are sent along the HTML not as separate resources,
  so the time to load the HTML increases (I'm talking about DOM ready vs full page load).
- Those images can't be cached, so the second visit to the page uses the same bandwith as the first one.

Just those two arguments should be enough to understand why it's better to use separate files unless you're talking about small images in css or other specific purpose where you know that it's better to embed the images

Comment: indeed. That's not for `<img>`, but maybe useful for JSON `img={name:'DSC0001.jpg', data:'data:image/jpeg...'}.`